# 'MQRC_BACKED_OUT' error in mule logs

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

We are observing 'MQRC_BACKED_OUT' error in our mule based application with connects to Webview MQ.

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2003' ('MQRC_BACKED_OUT').
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:223)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1112)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageProducer.java:1068)
```

I checked the ERROR CODE description at this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21039930

It says increase the log file size. Will doing this alone resolve the issue? I did not understand the WAIT INTERVAL part ? Could this issue be due to latency issue between the APP server and the MQ server?

Comment: Increasing the log size might solve the problem - however I think we would need more informtion about what has happening at the time of the failure.  What transactional work is going on?

Comment: We get this exception when our Transaction Manager tries to commit the transaction.

Comment: The wait interval part is about the time from the last get of a message and the request to commit

Comment: Is this wait Interval configurable in the MQ?

Comment: It is configurable in your application. It is either how long your application waits after doing a get and processing it before committing the transaction, or if you application is immediately committing the transaction after being informed there are no more messages to process, then it is the time specified on the get-wait.